# Javascript - How to "send" input

Tags: javascript, input, send

I am experimenting with Javascript and was wondering if I am able to send value from input (that is actually chat) to chat .
I already have website and was experimenting from customer side , Part of chat box is :
...

```
<div id="chat-input-wrapper">
 <input id="chat-input" placeholder="Type here" type = "text" maxlength="140">
</div>
```

NOTE : I have no button near chat that is used for sending input , so I can not use click option. **I want to do this from browser console .**

Already thankfull , 
BUDI.

Comment: Using ajax, write that in the console:
`m=document.getElementById('chat-input').value;with(new XMLHttpRequest())open("POST","yourpage.php"),send("message="+m);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FORM. The form is the HTML way to send data and it can be done via 2 methods, GET and POST

```
<form  method="post" action="datadestination">
    <div id="chat-input-wrapper">
        <input id="chat-input" placeholder="Type here" type = "text" maxlength="140">
    </div>
</form>
```

usually you will use a button for this, but since you are asking how to do it without, one of the things that a form does is that it captures the enter for example, so if you have that input inside a form, whenever someone hits enter it will be submitted(execute the action)

Comment: Thank you for reply . 
I am not really looking to do it from html . I need a way to do it from console in browser. 
The part of chat that is used for sending input is what I already stated . I need a way like a trigger function for javascript , but the way I tried it , it didn't work.
Chat works flawlessly when people enter value in input and press enter .I need to figure out how to press that enter.
Greeting! :)

Comment: you can find the form using a getelementbyid('id') and call the submit action like

    getelementbyid('form_id').submit;

What will be the trigger for you to send the input? the input has several events you can use. onblur for example.